# How to increase active connections in AWS RDS or how to upgrade from current DB instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have deployed my MERN stack app on AWS EC2 and have done clustering but my RDS is 2CPU and 8GB ram now with the increase in traffic my DB instance gives an error of maximum connections so how can I increase connection or upgrade my RDS instance?
Do I have to reconfigure RDS Settings as my website is in production so I don't want it to go down? Kindly Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what DB engine you are using so it's difficult to give a firm answer but, from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections),:

> The maximum number of simultaneous database connections varies by the DB engine type and the memory allocation for the DB instance class. The maximum number of connections is generally set in the parameter group associated with the DB instance. The exception is Microsoft SQL Server, where it is set in the server properties for the DB instance in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Assuming that you are *not* using MSSQL, you have a few different options:

1. Create a new ParameterGroup for your RDS instance, specifying a new value for `max_connections` (or whatever the appropriate parameter is called).
2. Use a different instance class with more memory as this will have a higher default `max_connections` value.
3. Add a [read-replica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html).
4. Make code changes to avoid opening so many connections.

1 and 2 will require a change to be made to your database in a maintenance window so there would be downtime. It sounds like you have a single RDS instance so it's possible to upgrade *without* downtime. The process is `backup-db -> restore-db to new instance -> upgrade restored instance -> change application to use restored instance` (you will need to manage any writes done between backup + switchover yourself).

3 is only relevant if the issue is that the number of connections are making `SELECT` queries. If this is an issue you would need to update connection strings to use the read-replica.

4 is a huge scope but it's probably where I would start (e.g. could you use connection pooling, or cache data to reduce the number of connections?).

Comment: Thanks for a quick Reply am using RDS mYSQL and I have a single Instance running